# Rails override validator message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, message

I have a site thats served in 2 flavours, English and French. Here's some code

```
app/views/user/register.html.erb
-----------------          
<% form_for .....>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %> 
<% end %>

app/models/user.rb
------------------
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :first_name

end
```

Now to display the error message in case if the site is being served  in the French version, I have

```
app/config/locales/fr.yml
-------------------------
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        empty: "ne peut pas être vide"
```

So if someone does not fill in a first name, the validator takes the name of the field and appends the custom message for empty clause giving

```
"First name ne peut pas être vide"
```

which is incorrect, coz 'First name' in French is 'Prénom', hence it should be

```
"Prénom ne peut pas être vide"
```

Please can someone suggest a way of achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Rails documentation for generate_full_methods in the ActiveRecord::Error class...

> Wraps an error message into a
>   full_message format.
>
> The default full_message format for
>   any locale is "{{attribute}}
>   {{message}}". One can specify
>   locale specific default full_message
>   format by storing it as a translation
>   for the key
>   :"activerecord.errors.full_messages.format".
>
> Additionally one can specify a
>   validation specific error message
>   format by storing a translation for
>   :"activerecord.errors.full_messages.[message_key]".
>   E.g. the full_message format for any
>   validation that uses :blank as a
>   message key (such as
>   validates_presence_of) can be stored
>   to
>   :"activerecord.errors.full_messages.blank".
>
> Because the message key used by a
>   validation can be overwritten on the
>   validates_* class macro level
>   one can customize the full_message
>   format for any particular validation:
>
> ## # app/models/article.rb   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> ```
> validates_presence_of :title, :message => :"title.blank"   end   #
> ```
>
> ## config/locales/en.yml   en:
>
> ```
> activerecord:
>   errors:
>     full_messages:
>       title:
>         blank: This title is screwed!
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem: [advanced_errors](http://github.com/markcatley/advanced_errors)

to specify custom error messages that do not include the field name if the first character is '^'. So, you'll have messages like

```
"^Prénom ne peut pas être vide"
```

and they'll show normally.